# Azure ftp uri not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ftp

I have a web site on azure and I have to ftp some files using asp.net to that server.

I am using following code which throws an exception "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

```
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://abcd-prod-xyz-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/TestFolder/");
        ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;
        ftpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
        ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = true;

        ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("TestDomain\TestCred", "TestCred");

        ftpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;

        try
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to specify the full file name of the remote file to be created in the .Create() call like the following example:

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://sss-xxx-red-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/test.png");
        ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;
        ftpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
        ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = true;

        ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"myuser\$myuser", "myuser_password");

        ftpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;

        try
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\_debug\test.png");
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int i = 1;
        }
```

References:

Uploading files via FTP
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

FTP credentials in Azure (been a while for me so I had to figure that out again)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/4d3ced02-9893-4d4f-9bed-d6ac1cd10e65/whats-my-ftp-username-and-password?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting

Comment: Hahh.. Silly mistake from me